# why can't i format a string list entry by using .title() in python 3.0 ?

Tags: python-3.x

for example, look at this. i'm unable to format the string entries of the list days_of_week as you can see in the output.

code:

```
days_of_week=['sun','mon','tues','wednes','thurs','fri','satur']
    print(days_of_week)
    i=0
    while i<=6:
        days_of_week[i].title()
        i+=1
    print(days_of_week)
```

output:

```
['sun', 'mon', 'tues', 'wednes', 'thurs', 'fri', 'satur']
['sun', 'mon', 'tues', 'wednes', 'thurs', 'fri', 'satur']
```

as you can see, the list remains unchanged/unformatted.

​

Comment: String methods never modify the string.

Comment: `days_of_week[i] = days_of_week[i].title()`

Comment: Also, `locale.DAY_1`...`DAY7`.

Answer (score 1):

change this to 
`days_of_week[i].title()`
this
`days_of_week[i]= days_of_week[i].title()`

as **strings are immutable in python** and no method on string object works inplace

Answer (score 1):

For future reference use comprehension:

```
days_of_week = [day.title() for day in days_of_week]
```

And you missed to add assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Alongside with the list comprehension:

`days_of_week = list(map(lambda x: x.title(), days_of_week))`  # using lamda expression